# Did the receiver open the mail?

Tags: gmail

With Gmail, is there some way to do that check?

Comment: For what it's worth, any solution you may find can be circumvented by some (usually simple) technological measure. Nothing to do with Gmail, it's because of the way email in general works.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can [try a service as SpyPig](http://www.spypig.com/) to sent you a notification when your email has been read.

> SpyPig is a simple email tracking
>   system that sends you a notification
>   email as soon as the recipient opens
>   and reads your message.
>
> It works with virtually all modern
>   email programs: Outlook, Eudora, Yahoo
>   Email, Gmail, Hotmail, AOL Email and
>   many others.
>
> **Basic Requirement**
>
> Both you and the recipient must use an
>   HTML email, not plain-text or
>   rich-text email. Visit the
>   [Requirements & Limitations page](http://www.spypig.com/requirements.php) to
>   learn more about SpyPig.

[Kudos to labnol.org](http://www.labnol.org/internet/email/check-yahoo-gmail-email-read-receipts/2150/) for the suggestion!

Comment: presumably this is done with `<img>` tags? Ah yes.. "SpyPig relies on the image download as the tracking device."

Comment: It's not perfect, but heck it does the job. Just not really useful in a professional email @Jeff

Comment: Thanks! btw, how does this `<img>` image download thing work?

Comment: at least i tell gmail to not render any images. i hate such sniffing around in general. it is almost as annoying as the "urgent" marker in mails.

Comment: @Lazer: pretty simple, add <img src="http://yourdomain.com/email1.png"> to your mail and then wait until "someone" is requesting that url from your server.

Comment: Given it embeds an image, and all modern email clients do not display images by default, this isn't a reliable solution at all.

Comment: Gmail doesn't provide a reliable solution @akira and @iAn Probably from a privacy standpoint, I couldn't agree more

Comment: it is not only gmail, the shoe fits every mail client. but, you know that :)

Comment: @iAn, If the email contains other images, the fact that someone has decided to display the images it likcly to mean they have in fact look at the email, rathern then just displayed it on screan.  So using a tracking image may be a good method.

Comment: @Ian Ringrose - you've missed the point. Just because an email contains more than one image, it doesn't mean the user is going to chose to display them. You should be able to read the contents of an email irrespective of if you have chosen to have the images display or not.

Answer (score 3):

Not if you use the web ui.  I think (but am not certain) that it would work if you use a desktop client that supports it.

See here for details about why it doesn't work and is generally unreliable:  http://knol.google.com/k/read-receipts-in-gmail#

Comment: As mentioned in the link, this method is not reliable either (just like the <img> tag tracker bug), it depends on the receiver to play along.

Comment: True, but people are generally happy if their client supports it.  A desktop client supporting read receipt (like Outlook) is what people think of at least.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in rchern's link:

By far the easiest and most reliable way to know if your recipient has read a message is to ask them in the message to send you a brief reply.

Answer (score 3):

Similar to the suggestion by @Ivo, **whoreadme** is, you guessed it, a tool that can track who has read and forwarded your emails.

> WhoReadMe is embedded a **transparent
>   tracking image** into your HTML e-mail.
>   The image is assigned with unique ID
>   and stored in WhoReadMe server. **Once
>   your recipient opens your e-mail,
>   tracking image will be loaded from
>   WhoReadMe server**. Therefore, WhoReadMe
>   is alerted to send you notification.

However, it still has the problems associated with this method of tracking if an email has read in that generally, **people will *not* have their email client set to download images by default**.